# loop within 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, and I am trying to find out which checkboxes should be checked and which not. I do get correct results, but if 2 checkboxes should be checked, I  get 2 sets of checkboxes, if 3 should be checked i get 3 set of checkboxes and so on... I make a numerous attempts to avoid that using break and continue statements, without success.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
foreach ($rooms as $room) {
    foreach ($searchQuerySelectedRooms as $selRoom) {
        if ($room['roomID'] != $selRoom) {
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="<?php echo $room['roomID']; ?>" style="float:left;width:20px; margin-right:10px;"/>
<?php
        } else {
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="<?php echo $room['roomID']; ?>" style="float:left;width:20px; margin-right:10px;" checked="checked"/>
<?php                                                                  
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Array `$rooms` prints the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [roomID] => 2
        [hotelID] => 10
        [roomtypeID] => 1
        [roomNumber] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [roomID] => 3
        [hotelID] => 10
        [roomtypeID] => 1
        [roomNumber] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [roomID] => 4
        [hotelID] => 10
        [roomtypeID] => 2
        [roomNumber] => 3
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [roomID] => 5
        [hotelID] => 10
        [roomtypeID] => 2
        [roomNumber] => 4
    )
)
```

While array `$searchQuerySelectedRooms` prints the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: please post your arrays too

Comment: sure...I will update the post in a minute...sorry

Comment: question has been updated...

Comment: please use in_array() to check for existence of value in array

Comment: should both loop remain? or one of them should be removed? if yes, which one?

Comment: foreach ($searchQuerySelectedRooms as $selRoom) { no need for this loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56644/discussion-between-user2417624-and-karthick-kumar-ganesh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this code

```
<?php
foreach ($rooms as $room) {
    if (in_array($room['roomID'], $searchQuerySelectedRooms)) {
        $checker = 'checked="checked"';
    } else {
        $checker = '';
    }

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="' . $room['roomID'] . '" style="float:left;width:20px; margin-right:10px;" ' . $checker . '/>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be reduced down to just a couple of lines (n.b. I've reformatted to make it easier to read on SO):

```
<?php foreach ($rooms as $room) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="rooms[]"
           value="<?= $room['roomID']; ?>"
           style="float:left;width:20px; margin-right:10px;"
           <?= in_array($room['roomID'], $searchQuerySelectedRooms)? 'checked="checked"':''?>/>
<?php } ?>
```

Take note of the short syntax to echo the result of a statement (  ) and also the short syntax for an if statement ( condition ? true output : false output )